# Notify external system with custom or Standard Platform Event for unhandled exceptions in batch job

Tags: platform-event, publish-subscribe

There is a simple scenario: we have defined an Apex Batch job that runs at night and we have to notify an external system in the event that an unhandled exception occurs when the job runs.

What is the best approach? Having the external system subscribe to a custom platform event or a standard platform event that gets fired with EventBus.publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using the [BatchApexErrorEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_batchapexerrorevent.htm)

> BatchApexErrorEvent messages are generated by batch Apex jobs that implement the Database.RaisesPlatformEvents interface and have unhandled Apex exceptions during processing.

[Reference and example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm?q=batchapexerrorevent)

You'll need to write a trigger that looks like

```
trigger MyBatchApexErrorEventHandler on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert) {
   Set<Id> asyncApexJobIds = new Set<Id>();
   for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt:Trigger.new){
      asyncApexJobIds.add(evt.AsyncApexJobId);
   }

   Map<Id,AsyncApexJob> jobs = new Map<Id,AsyncApexJob>(
    [SELECT id, ApexClass.Name FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id IN :asyncApexJobIds]

   );
   // do something with the values in jobs
}
```